# SQL INSERT - Can I insert null values if column count doesn't match?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, null

I get an error message that says "#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" when I try to insert the values below.  Is there any way to have the lines of data that are shorter automatically insert as null at the end without manually going into each line of code?

```
VALUES ('','BUF','','QB1','','QB BILLS','Face=0x52','#0','25','69','13','13','56','81','81','81','3','12','3'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','QB2','frank REICH','Face=0x22','#14','25','69','13','13','31','44','25','50','3','3','2'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','RB1','thurman THOMAS','Face=0x83','#34','38','69','63','25','75','50','10','7','8','8'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','RB2','jamie MUELLER','Face=0x51','#41','44','69','25','88','50','25','5','3','6','2'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','RB3','kenneth DAVIS','Face=0xa5','#23','38','69','25','19','50','31','5','2','7','2'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','RB4','don SMITH','Face=0x8b','#30','38','69','25','19','50','31','3','3','8','2'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','WR1','james LOFTON','Face=0x81','#80','25','69','38','13','50','56','1','8','13','6'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','WR2','andre REED','Face=0xb6','#83','25','69','56','13','56','69','1','9','10','10'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','WR3','don BEEBE','Face=0x40','#82','25','69','44','13','50','44','1','4','13','2'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','WR4','al EDWARDS','Face=0x9a','#85','25','69','19','13','50','44','1','4','7','2'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','TE1','keith MCKELLER','Face=0xb7','#84','25','69','38','50','50','50','1','6','7','6'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','TE2','pete METZELAARS','Face=0x50','#88','25','69','19','44','50','31','1','3','5','2'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','C','kent HULL','Face=0x1e','#67','25','69','38','69'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','LG','jim RITCHER','Face=0x7','#51','25','69','38','56'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','RG','john DAVIS','Face=0x24','#65','25','69','25','63'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','LT','will WOLFORD','Face=0x48','#69','25','69','25','50'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','RT','howard BALLARD','Face=0x88','#75','25','69','19','63'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','RE','bruce SMITH','Face=0x88','#78','44','56','69','75','25','81','116','7'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','NT','jeff WRIGHT','Face=0xb','#91','25','31','31','50','19','19','30','7'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','LE','leon SEALS','Face=0xac','#96','25','31','38','44','31','50','25','18'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','ROLB','darryl TALLEY','Face=0xad','#56','31','44','50','38','44','63','25','25'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','RILB','ray BENTLEY','Face=0x30','#50','25','31','38','38','31','56','13','10'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','LILB','shane CONLAN','Face=0x2f','#58','31','44','50','56','19','69','13','13'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','LOLB','c. BENNETT','Face=0x82','#97','38','50','63','63','19','69','29','7'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','RCB','nate ODOMES','Face=0xc3','#37','38','44','56','38','38','56','0','25'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','LCB','kirby JACKSON','Face=0x89','#47','25','31','44','38','50','50','0','64'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','FS','mark KELSO','Face=0x26','#38','31','38','50','38','44','44','2','39'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','SS','leonard SMITH','Face=0x84','#46','31','38','50','44','44','50','2','40'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','K','scott NORWOOD','Face=0x29','#11','56','81','81','31','44','44','6'); 
VALUES ('','BUF','','P','rick TUTEN','Face=0x20','#10','25','56','44','31','19','63','3');
```

Comment: No, not automatically. How are you generating these SQL statements?

Comment: The columns are in `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2)`. They need to match, because how would MySQL know which entries it can change into null

Comment: Why do I have a suspicion that the variable numbers of columns should really be stored as separate rows in an association/junction table?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the unwanted column from your mysql statement 
for example

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO files (1, 2, unwanted, 4)
 VALUES ('$01', '$02', '' ,'$04')");
```

make it

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO files (1, 2, 4)
  VALUES ('$01', '$02' ,'$04')");
```

or Add a variable which is null,

```
<?php
    $null = '';
VALUES ('$null','BUF','$null','ROLB','darryl TALLEY','Face=0xad','#56','31','44','50','38','44','63','25','25'); 
       ?>
```

Comment: Do you agree that you will need to do this manually and therefore doesn't answer the question?

Comment: You assume that TO uses PHP.

Comment: LOL, I thought he is using php

Comment: He will most likely use PHP, but we don't know that based on his post. ;-)

Comment: I'm not using PHP otherwise I would have tagged it... I'm just trying to create a database of 840 players that I will draw upon later to output data.  I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to insert the data into a SQL database and drawing blanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the following assumptions base on your current post. I assume you want to add the score of a football player to the same table as the fixed data from each player. I would not recommend this because you will continue to add a new *column* every time you like to add a score.

I have made the following example for you how you can make a score table and player table that will separates the fixed data like name of the player, picture, etc from the scores.

Try this:

SQL query:

```
SELECT players.name, group_concat(score.score)
FROM players
JOIN score
ON players.id = score.id_players
GROUP BY players.id;


CREATE TABLE players (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(30)
  );

CREATE TABLE score (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  score int,
  id_players int
  );

INSERT INTO players (name)
VALUES ('QB BILLS'), ('frank REICH');


INSERT INTO score (id_players, score)
VALUES (1,25),(1,69), (1,13),(1,13),(1,56),(1,81),(1,81),
(1,81),(1,3),(1,12),(1,3), (2,25),(2,69),(2,13),(2,13),(2,31),(2,44),(2,25),(2,50),(2,3),(2,3),(2,2);
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf39d/8)

Comment: Thanks, but that is not really what I'm looking to do.

Comment: @tecmosuperbowl can you explain in more detail what you are looking fore. In what form are you getting the data?